# An alternative to useing datetime_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, datetime-select

I'm not such a fan of using datetime_select. I think it renders ugly and isn't easy to deal with on post back.

How do most people deal with it? Wouldn't it be easier to use a plain textbox and use javascript to validate the input as a date? I will be persisting it as a DateTime value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a text box with a jquery datepicker and all was well in the universe.

Comment: yeah but that doesn't have the time. Can you go into detail about how you got the date and time to be selected?